# Recording via Xbox Game bar is not working on my computer

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues, windows-10, recording, xbox-game-bar

I am trying to record from the Xbox Game bar on my PC. I was recording, and it worked fine for a while, but recording became unavailable while I was currently recording, so I do not know where the kicked recording went. I went back to try to record again, but it said

> Gaming features are not available on windows 10 desktop or file explorer

It worked in the minecraft menu but not in a minecraft world.

I did not have anything else running in the background. Is there a fix, or is there another service to record Minecraft Bedrock Edition gameplay?

Comment: Was the game in focus when you tried to record? i.e. you were in the game, pressed Win+G and it gave that message

Comment: No. When I clicked to record it gave me that message

Comment: But you clicked record from in the game yes?

Comment: @Abraham I would recommend getting OBS and take like a 30 second clip; if the clip isn't laggy then I would keep using it because it is much better anyway, if the clip is laggy then you could just uninstall it

Comment: My dad has a gaming computer in my basement that I do not regularly use so I will try OBS on that *eventually*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the desktop active which is causing the issue.

Try pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> while in Minecraft next time.

Comment: I was in my minecraft world when it said that

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to do this from the Xbox Companion App.

Note that if you are streaming, some games have licensed music which *may* disable the ability, or disable the sound in the recording. Also, you will need to record from the desktop IF you are streaming to the Xbox App.

You can also record a certain number of minutes on the Xbox itself (settable in your account settings). If you set it for longer than one or two minutes, it may not always work properly - especially if you're running your hard drive near capacity. Just hit the Xbox key on the controller, followed by  That option may ALSO disappear, if you are already streaming, using some like the Twitch app, or the XBox Companiono on your PC.